# xcodebuild PLATFORM_NAME always == iphoneos

Tags: ios, xcodebuild

I am trying to build Xcode project from command line, using **iphonesimulator** as SDK. Here is the command line:

```
xcodebuild -scheme SchemeName -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator PLATFORM_NAME=iphonesimulator clean build
```

However, when I add a post-build action in Xcode like:

```
echo "PLATFORM_NAME: ${PLATFORM_NAME}"
```

it always outputs "PLATFORM_NAME: **iphoneos**" and not iphonesimulator.

Is this a bug, or there is something wrong in my build configuration? Thanks

Comment: Is there any iOS device is connected to your machine when you build?